# Rspec confusion of some gems and starting method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, factory-bot, faker

I am new to Rspec and learning it from EBooks and online Blog. I have some confusion about some gems and how should I go with testing? what they really do with Rspec and Testing?

These gems are following

**gem factory_girl

  gem 'capybara'

  gem 'faker'

  gem 'guard-rspec'

  gem 'launchy'**

I dont know why they are used for and which gem should I use at starting of learning Rspec? and another question is should I going for unit testing or Functional testing at staring poing of learning Rspec?

Please Help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`factory_girl` is used as substitute for test fixtures, to generate objects with predefined data for use in tests;

`capybara` is a integration testing tool;

`faker` generates sample test data;

`guard-rspec` works with `guard`, an automated testing tool;

`launchy` takes web pages generated by integration tests and opens them in a browser

You can get a better idea what each gem does by finding it on Github and perusing the README. If you're looking for an introduction to RSpec, the [RSpec docs](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec) are a good place to start. There are a number of tutorials that address testing -- eg. [this one](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/).